# Bresenham algorithm for drawing filled circle on 8bpp bitmap and on 24bpp bitmap in x86 assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm

I have working code for drawing filled circle using Bresenham algorithm on 8bpp bitmap. It is a routine called by C program. We are inputing the xc, yc, and r parameters for drawing the circle and its color(only few colors: red, blue, green, yellow). From C program we get all above parameters, width and height of the bitmap.

I recently stared learning x86 assembly, so I may not know few things.

I tried to change the routine to work on 24bpp bitmap, and I have few problems with it:

- Firstly the drawn circle have wrong dimensions its height is to big and its width is to small. It looks like ellipse.
- Secondly its placement on the bitmap is not like it should. Its yc coordinate seems to be ok, but xc its not.
- Thirdly if I tried to use color given by user I get almost invisible circle, because its color is almost white.
- While using some fixed color value like grey(127,127,127) I get left half in black and right half in grey.

I think I have a problem with getting proper values of R,G,B of a color and also in saving those values to the pixels.
I know that in 24bpp format the one pixel is stored in 3 bytes. I also implemented padding for width of bitmap.

Any help will be appreciated.

x86 routine:

```
    section .text
    global _circle

; arguments 
%define imeg    [ebp+8] ; first pixel address
%define width   [ebp+12] ; width of image 
%define height  [ebp+16] ; height of image
%define xc  [ebp+20] ;   x coord of center of circle
%define yc  [ebp+24] ;   y coord of center of circle
%define radius  [ebp+28] ; radius of circle
%define color   [ebp+32]

; local variables
%define x   [ebp-4]
%define y   [ebp-8]
%define d   [ebp-12] 
%define yi  [ebp-16]
; x,y d, and yi are for internal calculations (bresenham's algorithm)

_circle:
;============Prolog==========
   push ebp
   mov  ebp, esp
   sub  esp, 16     ; create space
   push edi
   push ebx
;============Body========== 
   xor ecx, ecx     ; ecx = 0
   mov ecx, radius  ; ecx = radius
   cmp ecx, 0        ; test radius, make sure it's great than 0
   jle _finish       ; if radius <=0 jump to _finish

   ;----------------------- Padding ------------
; calculate row size
   mov      eax, width      ; row size in pixels
   imul     eax, 3      ; row size* in bytes (3 bytes per pixel)
   add      eax, 3      ; 3 is the maximum value to fit on 2 least sign.     bits
   and      eax, 0fffffffch ; zero out 2 least sign. bits, to round up to multiple of 4   
   mov  width, eax
   ;-------------------------------------


; assignment of letter to color 
_getcolor:
   mov edx, color  ; edx = color
   mov ecx,0f9h
   cmp edx, 114    ; edx - r (=red)
   je _start        ; jump if equal r (=red)
   mov ecx,0fbh
   cmp edx,121      ; edx - y (=yellow)
   je   _start      ; jump if equal y (=yellow)
   mov ecx,0fah     
   cmp edx,103      ; edx - g (=green)
   je   _start      ; jump if equal g (=green)
   mov ecx,0fch     
   cmp edx,98       ; edx - b (=blue)
   je _start        ; jump if equal b (=blue)
   ;xor ecx,ecx

; Bresenham algorithm   
_start:
; create a starting point   
   xor edi, edi      ; edi = 0
   mov x, edi        ; x = 0
   mov edi, radius   ; edi = radius
   mov y, edi        ; y = radius
; create a decision parameter d
   mov edi, radius   ; edi = radius
   add edi, radius   ; edi = 2*radius
   mov ebx, 3        ; ebx = 3
   sub ebx, edi      ; ebx = ebx - edi = 3 - 2*radius
   mov d, ebx        ; d = 3 - 2*radius

_loop: 
; compare x and y 
   mov edi, x        ; edi = x (at the beginning = 0) 
   cmp edi, y      ; x - y
   ja _finish        ; jump to _finish if x > y


; =============== begginig of new for loop, which is filling the circle ================
    mov edi, x      ; edi = x
    mov yi, edi     ; yi = x    
_for_loop:  
    mov edi, yi     ; 
    cmp edi, y      ; yi - y
    ja _condition   ; jump to _finish if yi > y


    ; if x <= y (viz. start drawing pixel); first point (x + xc, yc + yi)
       mov edi, xc      ; edi = xc
       add edi, x       ; edi = x + xc.
       jl _secondpoint  ; if (x + xc) < 0 (viz. out of range), then skip this point
       mov ebx, width   ; ebx = width
       dec ebx          ; ebx = width - 1
       cmp edi, ebx     ; edi - ebx
       ja _secondpoint  ; if (x + xc) > (width - 1), then skip this point
       mov edx, yc      ; edi = yc
       add edx, yi     ; edi = yi + yc
       jl _thirdpoint   ; if (yi + yc) < 0 (viz. out of range), then skip this point and second point
       mov ebx, height  ; ebx = height
       dec ebx          ; ebx = height - 1
       cmp edx, ebx     ; edi - ebx
       ja _thirdpoint   ; if (yi + yc) > (height - 1) (viz. out of range), then skip this point and second point
       call _Draw
    ;draw second point (xc - x, yc + y)
    _secondpoint:
       mov edi, xc      ; edi = xc
       sub edi, x       ; edi = xc - x.
       jl _thirdpoint   ; if < 0 (viz. out of range), then skip this point
       mov ebx, width   ; ebx = width
       dec ebx          ; ebx = width - 1
       cmp edi, ebx     ; edi - ebx
    ja _thirdpoint  ; if > (width - 1), then skip this point
       mov edx, yc      ; edi = yc
       add edx, yi       ; edi = y + yc
       call _Draw
    ;draw third point (xc + x, yc - y)
    _thirdpoint:
   mov edi, xc      ; edi = xc
   add edi, x       ; edi = x + xc.
   jl _fourthpoint  ; if < 0 (viz. out of range), then skip this point
   mov ebx, width   ; ebx = width
   dec ebx          ; ebx = width - 1
   cmp edi, ebx     ; edi - ebx
   ja _fourthpoint  ; if > (width - 1), then skip this point
   mov edx, yc      ; edi = yc
   sub edx, yi     ; edi = yc - y
   jl _fifthpoint   ; if  < 0 (viz. out of range), then skip this point and second point
   mov ebx, height  ; ebx = height
   dec ebx          ; ebx = height - 1
   cmp edx, ebx     ; edi - ebx
   ja _fifthpoint   ; if > (height - 1) (viz. out of range), then skip this point and second point
  call _Draw
;draw fourth point (xc - x, yc - y) 
_fourthpoint:
   mov edi, xc      ; edi = xc
   sub edi, x       ; edi = xc - x.
   jl _fifthpoint   ; if < 0 (viz. out of range), then skip this point
   mov ebx, width   ; ebx = width
   dec ebx          ; ebx = width - 1
   cmp edi, ebx     ; edi - ebx
   ja _fifthpoint   ; if > (width - 1), then skip this point
   mov edx, yc      ; edi = yc
   sub edx, yi     ; edi = y - yc
   call _Draw
;draw fifth point (xc + y, yc + x)      
_fifthpoint:
   mov edi, xc      ; edi = xc
   add edi, yi      ; edi = xc + y.
   jl _sixthpoint   ; if < 0 (viz. out of range), then skip this point
   mov ebx, width   ; ebx = width
   dec ebx          ; ebx = width - 1
   cmp edi, ebx     ; edi - ebx
   ja _sixthpoint   ; if > (width - 1), then skip this point
   mov edx, yc      ; edi = yc
   add edx, x     ; edi = yc + x
   jl _seventhpoint   ; if  < 0 (viz. out of range), then skip this point   and second point
   mov ebx, height  ; ebx = height
   dec ebx          ; ebx = height - 1
   cmp edx, ebx     ; edi - ebx
   ja _seventhpoint   ; if > (height - 1) (viz. out of range), then skip this point and second point
   call _Draw
;draw sixth point (xc - y, yc + x)
_sixthpoint:
   mov edi, xc      ; edi = xc
   sub edi, yi      ; edi = xc - y.
   jl _seventhpoint ; if < 0 (viz. out of range), then skip this point
   mov ebx, width   ; ebx = width
   dec ebx          ; ebx = width - 1
   cmp edi, ebx     ; edi - ebx
   ja _seventhpoint ; if > (width - 1), then skip this point
   mov edx, yc      ; edi = yc
   add edx, x     ; edi = yc + x
   call _Draw
;draw seventh point (xc + y, yc - x)  
_seventhpoint:
   mov edi, xc      ; edi = xc
   add edi, yi      ; edi = xc + y.
   jl _eighthpoint  ; if < 0 (viz. out of range), then skip this point
   mov ebx, width   ; ebx = width
   dec ebx          ; ebx = width - 1
   cmp edi, ebx     ; edi - ebx
   ja _eighthpoint  ; if > (width - 1), then skip this point
   mov edx, yc      ; edi = yc
   sub edx, x     ; edi = yc - x
   jl _condition   ; if  < 0 (viz. out of range), then skip this point and second point
   mov ebx, height  ; ebx = height
   dec ebx          ; ebx = height - 1
   cmp edx, ebx     ; edi - ebx
   ja _condition   ; if > (height - 1) (viz. out of range), then skip this point and second point
   call _Draw
;draw eighth point (xc - y, yc - x) 
_eighthpoint:
   mov edi, xc      ; edi = xc
   sub edi, yi      ; edi = xc - y.
   jl _condition    ; if < 0 (viz. out of range), then skip this point
   mov ebx, width   ; ebx = width
   dec ebx          ; ebx = width - 1
   cmp edi, ebx     ; edi - ebx
   ja _condition    ; if > (width - 1), then skip this point
   mov edx, yc      ; edi = yc
   sub edx, x     ; edi = yc - x
   call _Draw
;Finally, all 8 pixels was drawn, so we go to the next step of the algorithm  

   inc dword yi
    jmp _for_loop
;================ End of for loop ==========================================


_condition:
   mov edi, d     ; edi = d
   cmp edi, 0     ; testing whether d < 0
   jge _ymm       ; if d >= 0 then y--
   mov edi, x     ; edi = x
   lea ebx,[edi+edi*3+6]  ; ebx = 4 * x + 6
   add d, ebx             ; edi = d + 4 * x + 6  
   jmp _xii
_ymm:               ; y--
   mov edi, x       ; edi = x
   sub edi, y     ; edi = x - y 
   lea ebx, [edi+edi*3+10]   ; ebx = 4 * (x - y) + 10
   add d, ebx              ; edi = d + 4 * (x - y) + 10 
   dec dword y
_xii:               ; x++
   inc dword x         ; edi = x + 1
   jmp _loop       ; repeat drawing points

_finish:
;============Epilog==========
   pop ebx
   pop edi
   mov esp, ebp
   pop ebp
   ret

;=====================================================   
_Draw

    mov eax, edx    ; eax = edx(==yd)
    mov ebx, width  ; ebx = width
    mul ebx         ; eax = yd * width
    add eax,edi     ; eax = eax + edi = yd * width + xd
    add eax,imeg

    mov ebx, [eax]
    mov bl,cl       ; in cl the color is stored(for 8bpp)
    ;mov ebx, 127 ; grey color

    mov [eax], ebx

    ret
```

routine in C for drawing filled circle:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

inline void _draw_circle_8(IMAGE *img, int xc, int yc, int x, int y, unsigned long c){
    putpixel(img, xc + x, yc + y, c);
    putpixel(img, xc - x, yc + y, c);
    putpixel(img, xc + x, yc - y, c);
    putpixel(img, xc - x, yc - y, c);  
    putpixel(img, xc + y, yc + x, c);
    putpixel(img, xc - y, yc + x, c);
    putpixel(img, xc + y, yc - x, c);
    putpixel(img, xc - y, yc - x, c);
}

void draw_circle(IMAGE *img, int xc, int yc, int r, unsigned long c) {
    if (xc + r < 0 || xc - r >= img->w || yc + r < 0 || yc - r >= img->h) {
        return;
    }

    int x = 0, y = r, yi, d;
    d = 3 - 2 * r;

    while(x <= y) {
        for(yi = x; yi <= y; yi ++) {
            draw_circle_8(img, xc, yc, x, yi, c);
        }
        if(d < 0) {
            d = d + 4 * x + 6;
        }
        else {
            d = d + 4 * (x - y) + 10;  // I added 10 which didn't typed when asking question
            y--;
        }
        x++;
    }
```

EDIT
Thanks for all your answers! I will try to follow your advices.

Comment: Need to post true code: `d = d + 4 * (x - y) + ;` does not compile.

Comment: Why do you store 4 bytes in your `_Draw` subroutine when a 24-bpp pixel only occupies 3 bytes? What is the purpose of `mov bl,cl` in the `_Draw` subroutine? Where are you multiplying your coordinates by the bitmap stride and pixel size before plotting a pixel? What are the values of the arguments? What you probably should do first is run this in a debugger, set a breakpoint at the start of your assembly code and step through it instruction by instruction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to assign colors based on a 6-bit DAC.

```
 ; assignment of letter to color 
_getcolor:
 mov     dl,color
 mov     ecx,00630000h
 cmp     dl,'r'
 je      _start
 mov     ecx,00636321h
 cmp     dl,'y'
 je      _start
 mov     ecx,00006300h 
 cmp     dl,'g'
 je      _start
 mov     ecx,00000063h     
 cmp     dl,'b'
 je      _start
 mov     ecx,00636363h ;Default white
_start:
```

Use this code to write a pixel in 24bpp.

```
_Draw:
 mov     eax,edx         ; eax = yd
 imul    eax,WidthInBytes ; eax = yd * WidthInBytes
 add     eax,edi
 lea     eax,[eax+edi*2] ; eax = yd * WidthInBytes + xd
 add     eax,imeg
 mov     ebx,ecx         ;Copy color
 shr     ebx,8
 test    eax,1
 jz      .even
.odd:
 mov     [eax],cl
 mov     [eax+1],bx
 ret
.even:
 mov     [eax],cx
 mov     [eax+2],bh
 ret
```

Is this a NASM requirement?

```
lea ebx,[edi+edi*3+6]  ; ebx = 4 * x + 6
```

in stead of

```
lea ebx,[edi*4 + 6]
```

The following code could lead you into problems. The length of 1 scanline for any video mode does not necessarily obey to this calculation. You might want to lookup VESA documentation in order to use the **LinBytesPerScanLine field at offset 50 of the VBE 3.0 ModeInfoBlock**.

```
;----------------------- Padding ------------
; calculate row size
mov      eax, width      ; row size in pixels
imul     eax, 3      ; row size* in bytes (3 bytes per pixel)
add      eax, 3      ; 3 is the maximum value to fit on 2 least sign.     bits
and      eax, 0fffffffch ; zero out 2 least sign. bits, to round up to multiple of 4   
mov  WidthInBytes, eax
```

;-------------------------------------

Also it would be nicer if you didn't modify the *input parameter WIDTH* but rather store this result in another local variable.

EDIT

The *width* that you use in the following code has to be the original value of *width* which is a **WidthInPixels**! You need to put the result of the padding calculation in an extra local variable **WidthInBytes** that you'll use only in the *_Draw* routine.

```
; if x <= y (viz. start drawing pixel); first point (x + xc, yc + yi)
   mov edi, xc      ; edi = xc
   add edi, x       ; edi = x + xc.
   jl _secondpoint  ; if (x + xc) < 0 (viz. out of range), then skip this point
   mov ebx, width   ; ebx = width
   dec ebx          ; ebx = width - 1
   cmp edi, ebx     ; edi - ebx
   ja _secondpoint  ; if (x + xc) > (width - 1), then skip this point
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort:)
` lea ebx, [edi+edi*3 +6] ` 
could be changed to 
` lea ebx [edi*4 +6] `

Comment: I tried to use your pices of code. While using both of them the colour is like right half is black, the circle border is also, but left is white.
The one to write a pixel in 24bpp is somehow working, because I got some colors, when I used some fixed values for ecx.

Btw why this pice of code don't work??
`   mov cl, byte 222
   shl ecx, 8
  mov cl, byte 69 
  shl ecx, 8 
  mov cl, byte 177  `
It only moves 177, so draw in light grey.

I also figured out that my code about padding is not corrrect.

Comment: When I don't use my code for padding I am getting not elipse, but circle. In fact 3 circles with radius 3 times smaller than it should be.
Any ideas why?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it is drawing a circle with the proper size;-)
But there is a bit shifting in the position. It is a bit more to the left, than it should be. For about 20 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to debug your assembler but have a suggestion how to go from correct C to optimized assembler with Visual Studio/Visual C:

1. Write the functionality as correct C code;
2. Compile;
3. In Visual Studio 2005, run the program and halt on your function(s). Now call up the assembler window. Select and copy the assembly code to a .txt file. End the debug session. The assembler looks like:

   ```
   ;if (!prm1) return (FALSE);
   004373D9  cmp         dword ptr [prm1],0
   004373DD  jne         MyFunction+16h (4373E6h)
   004373DF  xor         eax,eax
   004373E1  jmp         MyFunction+0B7h (437487h)
   ```
4. Edit the C file. Change the function heading to:

`void __declspec(naked) *MyFunction(struct MYTYPE *prm1, int prm2)
{
    __asm {
        push        ebp 
        mov         ebp,esp
        add         sp, LOCAL_PRM_SIZE`

You can access the parameters as e.g.:

```
        mov    eax,dword ptr [prm1]
```

Change the function exit to:

```
    mov         esp,ebp 
    pop         ebp  
    ret
    }
}
```

5. Remove stuff from the txt file until only the assembly remains. Paste this between the entry/exit. Note that you now have correct assembly. The assembly looks now a bit like:

   ```
   ;if (!prm1) return (FALSE);
       cmp         dword ptr [prm1],0
       jne         myLabel1
       xor         eax,eax
       jmp         label_exit 
   myLabel1:
   ```
6. Optimize what you have.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to follow your advice when I will have a bit more time than right now:)